# Jquery show/hide with scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have already got working the effect which it's that when you click on one year column (2012, 2011, 2010, etc) it shows the content of each year and hide the other ones. I have get it working, for example, scroll till "2011" column and click on it, it shows the content of it and hides the other content of the other years.

The problem it's that when I click, the animation does all the effects at the same time confusing the user, I think I have to do it with animation steps, but I haven't been able to come to a jquery solution.

What should I add to my code to fix this strange crazy effect?

My code:

```
/* Scroll Function */
function scrollto(position){
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollLeft: position
    }, 1000);
}

/* Calendar Scroll */
$(".sub_section_title").click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
$(".contenido_calendario").hide();
$(this).next(".contenido_calendario").toggle('slow');
scrollto($(this).offset().left - 352)
});
```

I have tried with .queue() this but it doesn't work:

```
$(".sub_section_title").click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".contenido_calendario").hide();
    $(".contenido_calendario").queue(function() {
        scrollto($(this).offset().left - 352);
    $(this).dequeue();
    });
    $(".contenido_calendario").queue(function() {
        $(this).next(".contenido_calendario").toggle('slow')
    $(this).dequeue();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is jquery's .queue()

http://api.jquery.com/queue/

You can also use delay()

http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: Hi, I put in the question what I have tried, it doesn't seem to work either.